# Wait form sheet to be dismissed - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss

I have a view presented as Form Sheet from the AppDelegate with this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let usernameVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChooseUsernameViewControllerID")
usernameVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(usernameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After I have presented it I have to wait the Form Sheet to be dismissed before continue execute the code... How can I pause the execution of the code until the Form Sheet is dismissed?

PS. The code to execute is:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
                self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainContainerViewControllerID")
                }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What code to excute?

Comment: @TonyHan I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do here, is add a delegate to your ChooseUsernameViewController, with exactly one method. The method should be called "ChooseUsernameDisappeared" or something similar. Then, add a viewDidDisappear method to your ChooseUsernameViewcontroller, and fire the delegate when this method is called. Then, implement the ChooseUsername delegate in your AppDelegate to listen for the disappearance. Then, you can execute the code.